# Ajax requests causing server to crash

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a website where students take online quizzes. Each time they select an answer (radio buttons for multiple choice) the following code is executed:

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
var questionId = $(this).parent().parent().find('.qid').val();
var answer = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertqanswerajax.php",
        data: {questionId: questionId, answer: answer},
    });

});
```

the insertqanswerajax.php code:

```
<?php session_start();
include_once('../includes/connect.php');     //connect to database
include_once('../functions/quizfunctions.php');   //all functions
$userSubject = $_SESSION['subject'];
$userGradeLevel = $_SESSION['gradeLevel'];
$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$questionId = $_POST['questionId'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];



insertQuizAnswer($questionId, $userId, $answer, 1);
$DB = null;

?>
```

and the insertQuizAnwer function:

```
function insertQuizAnswer($questionId, $userId, $answer, $testId){
global $DB;                                          
$standardsHandle = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO quizanswers (questionid, userid, answer, testid)
                                VALUES (:questionId, :userId, :answer, :testId)
                                ");   //get all benchmark grades for user
$standardsHandle->bindParam(':questionId', $questionId);
$standardsHandle->bindParam(':userId', $userId);
$standardsHandle->bindParam(':answer', $answer);
$standardsHandle->bindParam(':testId', $testId);
$standardsHandle->execute();
$standardsHandle = null;
}
```

The code works fine until the volume gets heavy (few hundred users taking tests). The server crashes and you get a default 500 error, the site comes back up after a minute or two. You can replicate the error simply by clicking one radio button over and over again.

My memory limit is 524 Megabytes, probably higher than my plan actually allows.

The reason this part of the code exists is to save users answers as they go, this allows them to come back later or pick up where they left off if the school network drops (which it does).

I am on a shared hosting plan and I know that has its limitations, I am trying to determine if there is a way to make this work or if it is simply not possible with my shared plan.

Comment: I think first you should check your error logs or ask your hoster for the logs.

Comment: I have checked the error logs, nothing comes up. I am under the impression that means that the server is not even getting the requests once it goes down.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I'd really recommend looking into using something like CouchDB, MongoDB etc for this kind of short-term data storage. They're much more lightweight, can handle concurrent users a lot better and will take far less memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with your hosting.
To resolve this issue, you have to buy a hosting plan with larger bandwidth (to handle multiple requests concurrently). You can discuss this with your hosting provider.